# Generating parallel feature.cs files using specflow 2.2.1 and MSTest V2

Tags: mstest, specflow

I'm running my unit tests in parallel using mstest v2 set to class level parallelism. However when I generate or regenerate the specflow feature.cs files (richt-click => 'Run Custom Tool' or 'Regenerate Feature Files') I get:

```
        [Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.ClassInitializeAttribute()]
    public static void FeatureSetup(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext testContext)
    {
        testRunner = TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner(null, 0);
        TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo featureInfo = new TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "UserPreferences", "\tIn order to customize my dashboards", ProgrammingLanguage.CSharp, new string[] {
                    "API"});
        testRunner.OnFeatureStart(featureInfo);
    }
```

If I change the following line in the feature file to:

```
testRunner = TechTalk.SpecFlow.TestRunnerManager.GetTestRunner();
```

It is able to run tests in parallel.
Is there a way to **force** specflow to generate the parallelized form of '.GetTestRunner()' in the feature.cs files?

Comment: In the code-behind file there is a header. Which version numbers do you see?

Comment: //  <auto-generated>
//      This code was generated by SpecFlow (http://www.specflow.org/).
//      SpecFlow Version:2.2.0.0
//      SpecFlow Generator Version:2.2.0.0
// 
//      Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//      the code is regenerated.
//  </auto-generated>

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that MSTest is not yet marked in SpecFlow as able to parallelize test execution.

See https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/blob/master/TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator/UnitTestProvider/MsTestGeneratorProvider.cs#L32

This method has to return UnitTestGeneratorTraits.ParallelExecution.

I created an issue for this: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/988

PRs are always welcomed!

Comment: Thanks Andreas, just fyi I'm the one that opened https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/984 and have it working locally, I should have a PR for it over the next week or so. And might pick up #988 as well.